# Two implications of an operator that preserves positivity on L2

Tags: measure-theory, operator-theory, lp-spaces, holder-inequality, contraction-operator

Suppose $(X,\mathcal{A},m)$ is a probability space. Let A be an operator on function spaces. I am currently taking a course in measure theory, and in the lecture slides the following two remarks are made.

1. If $A: L_2(X) \to L_2(X)$ preserves positivity and $A1=1$, then $A:L_{\infty}\to L_{\infty}$ is a contraction.
2. If $A:L_2(X) \to L_2(X)$ preserves positivity and also preserves an integral, then it extends to a contraction $A: L_1(X) \to L_1(X)$.

**My question** is why are the above statements true? In particular, the condition about preserving positivity seems difficult to use for me because what we want to show in both cases is a statement that can be expressed purely in terms of the norms of functions (in which case it doesn't matter whether the function is non-negative or not). The fact that we are trying to prove some kind of inequality involving norms also suggests some use of Holder's inequality, but I am struggling to fill in the details.

Answer (score 2):

1. Let $f\in L^\infty$  with $\|f\|_\infty=1$. Since $\operatorname{Re} f\leq1$, we have
   $$
   0\leq A(1-\operatorname{Re} f)=1-A(\operatorname{Re} f).
   $$
   Similarly,
   $$
   A(\operatorname{Im} f)\le 1.
   $$
   This shows that $Af\in L^\infty$. At this stage I'm not sure if there is an elementary argument. The one I know is that, begin positive on an abelian C$^*$-algebra, $A$ is completely positive. And completely positive maps satisfy $\|A\|=\|A1\|$. So $\|A\|=1$ and it is a contraction.
2. Because $A$ preserves positivity, we can do the following. The adjoint $A^*$ of $A$ also maps $L^2(X)$ to $L^2(X)$. Now, since $A$ preserves the integral,
   $$
   \int_X (A^*1)f=\langle A^*1,f\rangle=\langle 1,Af\rangle=\int_XAf=\int_Xf.
   $$
   As this can be done for any $f$, it follows that $A^*1=1$. Also, since $A$ preserves positivity, so does $A^*$: if $g\geq0$ and $f\geq0$, then
   $$
   \int_X (A^*g)\,f=\int_Xg\,Af\geq0. 
   $$
   Again as $f$ can be any non-negative function we get that $A^*g\geq0$. So $A^*$ is in the conditions of item 1, and this means that $A^*$ is an $L^\infty$ contraction.

If we write $|Af|=g\,Af$ with $|g|=1$, then
$$
\int_X|Af|=\int_X(Af)\,g=\int_Xf\,Ag\leq\int_X|f|\,|Ag|\leq\int_X|f|,
$$
and so $A$ is an $L^1$-contraction.